# Photoshop action to reduce size and save in separate folder?

Tags: photoshop

I am wondering if someone could help lead me in the right direction for this. I would like to create a photoshop action that does the following:

1. Do a few things to process an image
2. Save the image as a jpg
3. reduce the image size by half
4. Save it in a sub folder called '50'
5. Reduce it by half
6. save in a sub folder called '25'
7. Reduce it by half again
8. Save in a sub folder called '12'

The images will be differently sized and differently named to start.

Comment: This is bordering on off topic, because it doesn't pertain to photography per se. You could be resizing anything. You might have just as much, if not more, luck over on the graphic design SE

Comment: Discussion to determine if this is on topic here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/are-photoshop-action-questions-on-topic

Comment: @Brodie: Is this a general graphic design question, or is it specifically related to photography? If it is the former, I can migrate this question to the SE Graphic Design site, where you might have better luck getting the answer you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write a Photoshop script. It is relatively easy if you have had previous experience with programming. You can write scripts in JavaScript (is my language of choice), AppleScript or VisualBasic (I wonder who'd use the latter one!).

My suggestion would be:

1. Create an action or record an action using a [ScriptListener](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/photoshop.htm)
2. Save image using Document.save()
3. Resize using Document.resizeImage()
4. Repeat steps 2&3 as long as you need with different parameters.

If you are not familiar with programming, then have a look at Image Processor in your File->Scripts menu. It allows you to resize images and store them under a different name.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I do have programming experience but not in making PS actions so this gives me somewhere to start - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create few Photoshop actions. 
First action can do your transformations, and save it as JPEG.
Second action can reduce your image by half, and save it to the folder called 50
Third action can reduce your reduced image by half, and save it to folder called 25
Fourth action can reduce it again, and save it to the folder 12.

If you don't know how to create Photoshop actions, you can read it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TsXQR5NUUA) or [here](http://blog.epicedits.com/2008/03/07/how-to-create-photoshop-actions/). Regards!